# Directional derivative - angle between the vector and coordinate axes

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

Doing an exercise a about directional derivatives, it was required to find the derivative of a given function $f(x,y,z)$ in the direction of the vector $ \vec{v}$ that forms with the coordinates axes $OX, OY, OZ$  the angles $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, respectively. The book gives the following formula to solve the exercise:

$$\frac{df}{d\vec{v}}(x_o, y_o, z_o) = \vec{\nabla } f(x_o, y_o, z_o ) \cdot(\cos\alpha, \cos\beta, \cos\gamma)$$

In 2 variables (using sine and cosine of the angle $\alpha$ formed with $OX$), it is easy to see the formula using that $\sin^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \alpha = 1$. But, how can I show that $||(\cos\alpha, \cos\beta, \cos\gamma)|| = 1 $ using that $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \pi /2$? 
Maybe it is more a trigonometry problem than calculus.

Thanks!

Comment: Let's pick $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=\pi/6$; we have that $\cos \alpha = \cos \beta = \cos \gamma = \sqrt{3}/2$, but $$\sqrt{\cos^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \beta + \cos^2 \gamma}= \sqrt{3 \cdot \frac{3}{4}} = \frac{3}{2} \ne 1 $$

Comment: @Dedalus thank you. Indeed, this formhla is not correct. In this case, I don't understand why should we do this, since this vector do not have norma 1

Comment: I am not sure that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma = \pi/2$, perhaps $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi$. I have seen this identity before. Take a unit vector and then consider the scalar product with each unit vector of the axis. You'll get the identity. I am not sure on the angle limitation though.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed just a trigonometric problem in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The cosine rule states that
$$
|\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}|^2=|\mathbf{a}|^2+|\mathbf{a}|^2
+2|\mathbf{a}|\,|\mathbf{b}|\cos\theta,
$$
or equivalently
$$
\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}=|\mathbf{a}|\,|\mathbf{b}|\cos\theta,
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle formed by the vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and
$\mathbf{b}$. In your case, this gives, assuming that $\mathbf{v}$ is a
unit vector,
$$
v_1=\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{e}_1=\cos\alpha\quad\text{ etc.},
$$
and hence
$$
\mathbf{v}=(\cos\alpha,\cos\beta,\cos\gamma).
$$
As a consequence,
$$
1=|\mathbf{v}|=|(\cos\alpha,\cos\beta,\cos\gamma)|
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's true that $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}$, but we do not need it.

The length of the projection of $v$ on the $x$-axis is $||v||\cos\alpha$.
Similarly, the length of the projection of $v$ on the $y$ and $z$ axes are $||v||\cos\beta$ and $||v||\cos\gamma$ respectively.

So, we can write $v=(||v||\cos\alpha, ||v||\cos\beta, ||v||\cos\gamma)$.

We already know that the unit vector pointing in the same direction as $v$ will be $\displaystyle\frac{v}{||v||}$, which we now know is equivalent to $v=(\cos\alpha, \cos\beta, \cos\gamma)$. Ergo $\left|\left|(\cos\alpha, \cos\beta, \cos\gamma)\right|\right|=1$.